# How to setup SSL with Ionic 4

Tags: javascript, typescript, cordova, ssl, ionic-framework

I want to create a ssl encryption for my ionic app.

I've generated a certificate according to [this tuturial](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/ssl-generate), its located in the default folder.

Furthermore I've found [this documentation](https://github.com/silkimen/cordova-plugin-advanced-http), but I have no idea how to implement the given code

```
// enable SSL pinning
cordova.plugin.http.setServerTrustMode('pinned', function() {
  console.log('success!');
}, function() {
  console.log('error :(');
});
```

into my existing constructor

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private transfer: FileTransfer) {
    this.fileTransfer = this.transfer.create();
    // I guess its supposed to be here
   }
```

and how to use the generated certificate.

In the end, I want my REST API to work with the **https://** instead of the **http://**

Comment: so you want ssl for test and development purposes on your local machine correct?

Comment: For now yes, but I want to send Api calls to my vm aswell